# Variable transformation: from angle to coordinates

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, constraint

I have the following problem: Let $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ be an angle and let $f(\theta)$ be a function such that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta)d \theta=1$. Now let consider the following transformations: $x_1=\cos(\theta)$ and $x_2=\sin(\theta)$ with the constraint $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$.

If you know $f(\theta)$, how can you find $f(x_1,x_2)$ given the transformation and the constrained show above? I am able to find the density arising by a variable transformation when there is no constrains and you move from a $p$ to another $p$ dimensional space. Here we start from a 1-dimensional space ($\theta$) to a 2-dimensional space ($x_1,x_2$) and there is a constraint

Thanks.

EDIT 1: I just copied here my reply to whuber (see below), to add more details and to be more clear

Comment: Are you asking how to find an angle, given its sine and cosine?

Comment: No of course. I am asking: If you know $f(\theta)$, how can you find $f(x_1,x_2)$ given the transformation and the constrained show above?  I am able to find the density arising by a variable transformation when there is no constrains and you move from a $p$ to another $p$ dimensional space. Here we start from a 1-dimensional space ($\theta$) to a 2-dimensional space ($(x_1,x_2)$) and there is a constraint

Comment: Given that $x_2 = \sqrt(1 - x_1^2)$, you can re-write $f(x_1, x_2)$ as just $f(x_1)$.  This should simplify things some...

Comment: @jbowman , no.  Can be + or - on value of x2, corresponding to a different $\theta$.